# Why doesn't Flask SSE demo work with stream_template?

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events

I am trying to get the SSE (Server Sent Event) demo to work in flask.

```
@app.route('/sse-demo')
def sse():
    def delay():
        for i, c in enumerate("hello"*10):
            time.sleep(.5)  # an artificial delay
            yield i, c
    # with render_template it works!
    #return render_template('sse_demo.html', data=g())
    # with stream_template it doesn't work!
    return Response(stream_template('sse_demo.html', data=delay()))
```

My **sse_demo.html** template looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Send javascript with template demo</title>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #data {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<div id="data">nothing received yet</div>
{% for i, c in data: %}
<script>
  $("#data").text("{{ i }} {{ c }}")
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

It works fine with **render_template**. I see /sse-demo url prints **1 h** to **49 o**.

But with **stream_template**, my page waits for some time and prints **49 o**.

Why?